# Selectize.js - Enforce At Least One Item From Select To Be Picked

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I have used the `allowEmptyOption : false`  but it has not helped.
I need to always have at least one item selected (the first one in the list is fine to default to).

I am not sure how to quickly and easily do this.  It seems like it should be simple but I must be overlooking something in the documentation.  The way I have my code, currently the select returns a blank or null value when I don't want it to.

Just a note.  I am using the `clearOptions()` and `addOption()` methods to load items into the select.  After all options are loaded, I want to then **select** the first item in the dropdown.  That is all I really want to do.  Any easy way of doing this using the options or programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using selectize events works for me:

```
// add 'staff' and maintain if attempt by user to remove
rolesStz.addItem('staff', true); 
rolesStz.on("item_remove", function(item) {
  if(item == "staff")
    this.addItem(item);
});
```

Running on:

```
// The selectized obj
var $roles = $('.input-roles');
$roles.selectize({
  options: roles
});
var rolesStz = $roles[0].selectize;
```

See also:
https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/events.md